# How to use the Python package inside a project

Tags: python, module, package

I have the following directory structure:

```
├── DynamicProgramming
│   ├── 0-1_kp_problem.py
│   ├── b.py
│   ├── largest_contigous_subarray.py
│   ├── longest_common_substring.py
│   ├── min_change_for_given_money.py
│   ├── optimal_matrix_chain.py
│   ├── Readme.md
│   └── wis.py
├── helper
│   ├── a.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── Readme.md
```

The `helper` directory contains the library functions which will be used all over the code. How can I import the helper package from the scripts inside `DynamicProgramming` without adding it to the path?

Edit=>

I cannot move `helper` directory inside `dynamicProgramming` because there can be more than one directories using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
from ..helper import a
```

[See python docs on packages.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: Yeah but I can only do that if the file I am using it in is a package itself

Comment: It sounds like `helper` directory contains some common functionality that will be used from other places besides `DynamicProgramming`.  In that case perhaps you should think about adding 'helper' directory to `PYTHONPATH`.  If you are using virtual environments you could easily add/remove the `helper` directory to `PYTHONPATH` when the virtual environment is activated/deactivated.  Then you could simply use an absolute path in your import.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your code from project root folder, you are likely to succeed with `import helper` or `import helper.a`. If not, you would have to add current directory to PYTHONPATH:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH="."
```

## better use project `setup.py`

Instead of playing with `PYTHONPATH` (what can be tricky business sometime), you shall create your project as python package.

You add `setup.py` into your project root, specify attributes of that package and build it from it.

`setup.py` can define multiple packages at once, but generally it is more often
using only one. For this purpose it would be better moving the `helper` package
into `DynamicProgramming` structure and import it from there.

Search for `setup.py` python packaging tutorials, it requires some study, but it will pay back.